# How to load sprite sheets that clamp to the sprite, excluding the background?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm having a lot of trouble googling for this because I don't really know the terminology for it. This HAS to be a common problem though. I want to iterate through a sprite sheet, but I want it to IGNORE the transparent background around the sprite and not include that as part of what's displayed.

For example, if I have a few frames, I want to iterate through each frame and load that image. Then, in that frame, I want to narrow it down by drawing a rectangle around the image itself, not the extra "background". This would probably be accomplished by finding the corners of the sprite which are non-transparent pixels (Not sure how this part works).

Does this make sense? Again, not sure exactly which words to use here...let me know if this is unclear.

The goal here is loading sprites that are exactly square with other frames, so they won't wobble or bounce unintentionally.

Thanks much!!

Comment: For what it's worth, I generally find it's best to do this sort of "adjustment" prior to using a spritesheet in a game. That way the game code remains as simple as possible and doesn't need to delay the user with "fixes". As for the fix itself, my experience is that automation of finding a given sprites origin is rarely successfull. e.g. a walking character may have his arm outstretched to one of the sprite which means the sprite's "origin" would be incorrectly too far to one side.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks. I've never done animation before, but my assumption is that if I have a sprite sheet with frames that aren't "square" with each other, it won't look right when animated. Like you said, the origin would be too far one way or something. I figured a programmatic fix would be easier...perhaps not :)

Comment: @PlanetLotus A spriteset should either a) be orthogonal (all sprites already in the right places) or b) have a description record of some sort that defines the locations for you.  Doing pixel-level detection of framing and offsets is notoriously unreliable.

Comment: Interesting. I'm very new to this so I really appreciate the insight. I guess it's a matter of me getting the sprites right...the main problem is this sprite "sheet" wasn't designed for programming (they're not equally spaced apart) so I had to redo it and now I'm not sure if I'm getting the origins right in each frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working on my first game as well and I had a similar problem with the transparent areas around my sprites, in this case for collisions.

What I did was set it up so that each sprite has a position, a height, a width and Padding for X and Y.

```
Vector2 position = new Vector2(100,100);
int frameHeight = 48;
int frameWidth = 48;
int paddingX = 4;
int paddingY = 3;
```

With that info you can get what you need, for instance for the rectangle that represents the bounding box around the sprite I can use:

```
boundingRectangle = new Rectangle(
  (int)position.X + paddingX, 
  (int)position.Y + paddingY, 
  frameWidth - (paddingX * 2), 
  frameHeight - (paddingY * 2));
```

I read this in XNA 4.0 Game Development by Example by Kurt Jaegers (Which has been a ton of help for me)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't understand though...how are you determining the size of the transparent padding? And are you finding a unique padding for every single frame? If that's the case, wouldn't it possibly be easier to just define the locations of the sprites on the sheet and not have to iterate through rows of sprites?

Comment: In my case I am using it for collisions and am currently using the same padding for each frame (It is a side shooter so your ship does not change too much as it animates) I still needed the padding because it felt like you would get hit by a graze or a shot through the engine exhaust. I may also change the padding to be 4 values rather than 2 so the rear padding can be larger than the front. I determined the size of the padding by examining the graphics in an edtor but ended up making it a bit larger as I worked on it because it just felt better playing with an extra pixel or two of padding.

Comment: Ohh gotcha. I'm not sure that will work for mine because the problem I have is that, for example, one of the "walk right" frames is horizontally longer than the "stand still" frame. Therefore, my generic frame is much larger than some of the sprites, but the size of the sprite varies. That's why I wanted to programmatically clip to the size of the sprite based on the amount of transparency.